# Enviar correos cuando utilizas diferentes configuraciones

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, email, smtp

Trabajo con Windows Forms, C#, Visual Studio 2015 la app que estoy implementando envía correos esta configurado con Gmail, pero ¿que pasa cuando otros usuarios tienen otras configuraciones?, quiero decir que cada usuario final que use la app tiene diferente correos como Hotmail, Gmail, WebMail, Outlook entonces el detalle es que la configuración del puerto SMTP cambia y eso hace que ya no envie los correos, ¿Que podría hacer, se me ocurrió al momento que ponen el correo que va enviar tomar el nombre del proveedor de correo para cambiar el puerto?, ¿abra otra solución?

Saludos!

Comment: Pedro realmente no te entiendo. Cada correo tiene su propia configuracion. El usuario deberia agregarla al sistema.

Comment: Trabajas con windows forms tu configuracion de correo puede estar en el config file ahora si tu correo de servidor cambia dependiendo del cliente es mejor que tengas esos datos en digamos una tabla configuracion de correo por cliente.

Comment: Lo que pretendes es que desde el equipo donde este instalada la aplicación se envie el correo con la cuenta del usuario?

Comment: @gbianchi, me explico mejor, los correos están en una tabla es mas practicamente es para una empresa cada empresa que hace uso de la app configura su correo por ejemplo yo configure un correo con Gmail, mi cuenta mi pass el puerto smtp y listo con eso puedo enviar correos a cualquier proveedor, el tema es cuando el cliente que configura para enviar sus correos tiene hotmail, yahoo, webmail, etc ahí tengo el problema, tendría que averiguarme los puertos smtp de todos los correos hacer una lista y por regex ver que proveedor es para luego ver que puerto smtp le pongo.

Comment: ESa es una opcion. Pero por lo general, el usuario es quien pone toda la info sobre el correo, y vos solo la guardas en algun lado. Tener una tabla con todos los correos existentes, inclusive si tiene un correo interno, suena como medio imposible. Cuando abrias outlook de escritorio te pregunta todos los datos, no los tiene precargados. Esa info se puede guardar en el lugar que gustes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los datos del servicio de `smtp` varian en cada implementacion no puedes ponerlo fijo, debes poder configurarlo.

Para eso existe el `app.config`

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="xx@gmail.com">
      <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" password="password" userName="xx@gmail.com" enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Si poner usuario y password no lo vez seguro puede encriptar esa seccion de configuracion, como explico aqui

[Envió del mail usando config seguro](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2012/07/mailmessage-envia-mail-con-gmail-13.html)

se usa el comando de asp.net para generar una key en encriptacion

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "MailSendKeys" –exp
```

que se puede exportar

```
aspnet_regiis -px "MailSendKeys" "C:\MailSendKeysFile.xml" -pri
```

para llevar a la pc de los usuario.

Esa key de encriptacion sera usara para aplicar seguridad en la configuracion

Comment: Leandro, el tema es que cada usuario que use la app configura su correo yo tengo cuenta en gmail, otro usuario puede tener su cuenta en hotmail y así sucesicvamente, el tema es que por cada proveedor que configures cambia el puerto SMTP ese es el detalle, claro esta que una vez que configuras una cuenta le puedes enviar a cualquier proveedor, espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Había pensado en SendGrid ó talvez en Mailgun, lo que pasa que solo dan para hacer envios 10. 000 a 20, 000 correos es muy poco ya que el sistema envía comprobantes electrónicos y cada cliente(usuario final) sus ventas varían.

Comment: pero se puede configurar el smtp de gmail, hotmail, etc con solo cambias el app.config. Si usas servicio como SendGrid estos son pagos. Podrias si quieres crear tu propio servicio y exponerlo que recba la notificacion y sale poruna unica configuracion de smtp que definas en ese servicio